# Webpack Module build failed when importing React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a project to integrate React and ASP.Net together. I've made the initial `Hello World` and every works as expected (not hard :p). I'm using webpack with babel-loader to generate my `bundle.js.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<h1>LPMU</h1>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./App.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'babel-preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After this worked out, I tried to add my App.js component and all other components into my react folder, inside Scripts on my ASP.NET project. I'm not doing the `export default App` since I'm using the `ReactDOM.render()`. I import my components into my App.js as usual:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Landing from './Landing';
import * as lpmuGlobal from './lpmu-global';
```

And then I just render the App component:

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))`

Now when I run `npm run webpack` again, I get 2 problems, which are the following:

```
  size   name  module    status
  704 B  0     ./App.js  built failed ✖

  Δt 596ms (1 asset hidden)


./App.js
  0:0  error  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

configuration
  0:0  warning  The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to
                'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or
                'production' to enable defaults for each environment.

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)
```

I've been searching for a solution, but since I'm really new to webpack, I don't know what happens, if I need anything else on my `webpack.config.js`, if I have to import my components in any other way or whatever.

ALso this is my `json.package`:

```
{
  "name": "lpmu-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Integración de ReactJS con ASP.NET",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "DPS",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "webpack-command": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually define your App component?

Comment: Of course, I'm doing the `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))` after the `class App extends Component { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have not added a `.babelrc` file or babel options to your `package.json` file to provide babel options.

> In order to enable the preset you have to define it in your .babelrc
>   file

Add babel option to your package.json as such :

**package.json:**

```
 {
  "name": "lpmu-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Integración de ReactJS con ASP.NET",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel":{
   "presets": ["env","react"]
  }
  "author": "DPS",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "webpack-command": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Go through the below links for further clarification:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc.html

https://babeljs.io/en/setup/#installation

**About the warning :**

Webpack 4 needs you to include the `mode` option to your configuration, as you would usually want to have development and production configurations separate.

Go through the link below which explains in detail how to set configurations.
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./App.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'babel-preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've made the changes and read the docs, the warning disappeared but I still get the error: `./App.js
  0:0  error  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):` :(

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1260 - Check this issue. It is mentioned that a similar issue exists because context is using relative path instead of absolute. @DavidAK

Comment: I solved it but it wasn't a route problem, Now webpack tells me about an error on my syntax with an arrow function, which is kind of weird because it has babel-react as a dependency ... `ERROR in ./App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (183:24)

  181 |     // --------------- HANDLERS BOTONES ---------------
  182 |
> 183 |     handleAñadirVentana = (tipoVentana) => {
      |                         ^
  184 |` And thanks for all your help

Comment: Ok I made it installing `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and adding `plugins: ['transform-class-properties']` into webpack.config.js now I just need my css to load :)